# Finding the # of sequences in an array

Tags: matlab, numbers, sequences

I need to report the # of sequences in an array. For example:

`A=[ 1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     1     1    -1    -1     1     0     1     1]`

and I have to report the # of times a number comes consecutively, such as, one sequence of

`5 -1s ([-1 -1 -1 -1 -1])` and one sequence of

`4 -1s ([-1 -1 -1 -1])`.

How can I find how many sequences of numbers there are?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com). You might also want to explain what programming language you are using.

Comment: I am using Matlab and I tried using ismember function so that I could find a set in the target array, however it did not give me the number of sequences embedded in my target array. Is there a particular function that i am missing ?

Comment: Why don't you just loop over the array and track the status as you progress?

Comment: For the number of sequences `1+sum(diff(A)~=0)` should work.

Comment: thank you I tried that @user1884905 but it still does not give me what I need. What I need is a report of the frequency of repeating sequences. For example for the array A (A=[ 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 0 1 1]) there are 1 sequence of 5 -1s, 1 sequence of 4 -1s, 4 sequences of 2 1 or -1s and no sequence of 3 anything.. It is similar to chunking groups of consecutively repeating numbers.

Comment: @user2060814 you are aware that you have 3 times 4 -1s in your example, since a single 5 -1s include 2 times 4 -1s...

Comment: @user2060814 Ah, ok. Then I misread your question. I thought the first part asked about how to get the total number of sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to perform this task

```
function [rl data] = runLength( vec )
% run length encoding for vector vec
rl = ( find( vec ~= [vec(2:end), vec(end)+1] ) );
data = vec( rl );
rl(2:end) = rl(2:end) - rl(1:end-1);
```

Applying run-length encoding to `A`

```
>> [rl data] = runLength( A )
rl =
   [ 2 5 1 1 4 2 2 1 1 2 ]
data =
   [ 1 -1 0 1 -1 1 -1 1 0 1 ]
```

So, if you are interested in the number of sequences of length > `n` all you need is

```
>> nnz( rl > n )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few number of possible element values in `A` (as in the example in the question where there only are three values, `-1`, `0` and `1`) you could loop through these and use the following few steps to get the lengths of the different sequences.

Here is an example checking `A == -1`:

```
A = [1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 0 1 1];
B = [0, A==-1, 0];
```

Use the `diff()` function to find the beginning and end of each sequence and subtract the two vector to get the sequence lengths.

```
>> C = find(diff(B)==-1)-find(diff(B)==1)

C =

     5     4     2
```

Here we can see that there is one sequence of length five, followed by one of length four and one of lenth two. We could also use `histc()` to get the frequency of these lengths in a vector.

```
>> D = histc(C,1:max(C))

D =

     0     1     0     1     1
```

Repeating the procedure with another value, for example checking `B = [0, A==1, 0];` gives us:

```
C =

     2     1     2     1     2

D =

     2     3
```