# MATLAB-How to count 0s and 1s in a vector

Tags: matlab

Let a vector `v` with length `n` be `v = randi([0 1],1,n)`, containing 0s or 1s randomly.

What is the effective way to get a vector indicating how many 0s or 1s there are in each 0-segment or 1-segment alternatively?

Example:

```
v = [1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]   ----> 
    counts = [0 1 3 2 2 1]  (*0* zero, *1* one, *3* zeros, ....)

v = [0 0 1 0 0 0]   ---->
    counts = [2 1 3]
```

P.S. Always count 0s first, if the vector starts with a 1, then the first entry of the result vector, i.e. counts(1), should be a 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the # of sequences in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809429/finding-the-of-sequences-in-an-array)

Comment: @Shai I think it is not a duplicate because this one appears to be about 0 1 vectors (Thus allowing simpler solutions than the referred question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly simple way to do it:

```
diff(find(diff([inf v inf])))
```

It should not be hard to expand if you also want to know which value correspond to each segment.

Comment: you beat me to it! I was just writing a similar solution. :)

Comment: Explanation: `diff` is from the dsp part and simply calculates the differences between vector components (that vector is one component shorter than its input, that is why we have to add two elements in the end, as diff is applied twice BTW). The `find` function returns the indices / positions of the non-zero components, diffing it means calculating the constant segment lengths (very elegant!). What puzzled me was the use of `[inf v inf]` but it simply ensures that the first and last component always show up (because the difference there is non-zero). One could yield the same with `[2 v 2]`.

Comment: The use of `inf` before the input vector does not assure that zeros are always counted first in the case that there are no zeros. Your solution gives `[1   3   2   2   1]` where the OP wants `[0  1   3   2   2   1]`. You need to change it a bit to `diff([1 find(diff([0 v inf]))])`.

Comment: @beaker is correct, that was the post scriptum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (it always counts zeros first, even if they don't exist):

```
aux = cumsum(abs(diff([0 v])));
counts = histc(aux, 0:max(aux));
clear aux;
```

Comment: Explanation: `diff` marks the start of a constant segment within the vector. By mapping all non-zero spots to +1 with `abs` and applying the cumulative sum `cumsum` the segment values are replaced with segment-length times their enumeration index. E.g. `0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   3`. The histogram / frquency count via `histc` then nicely creates the segement bins and as value their length. Clever. The padding `[0 v]` instead of plain `v` ensures the P.S. requirement.